# How can i see the username of my followers in instagram

Tags: python, api, instagram

I want to see the list of my followers in Instagram by python. I write this code

```
from InstagramAPI import InstagramAPI
username="*******"
InstagramAPI = InstagramAPI(username, "******")
InstagramAPI.login()
InstagramAPI.getProfileData()
followers = InstagramAPI.getTotalSelfFollowers()
print (followers[0])
```

It works fine and show

```
{u'username': u'yasinyasinyasinl', u'has_anonymous_profile_picture': True, u'profile_pic_url': u'https://instagram.fevn1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/19319123fc5a0016b6fd518cfa7058ce/5D7C0DF1/t51.2885-19/44884218_345707102882519_2446069589734326272_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fevn1-1.fna.fbcdn.net', u'full_name': u'yasin', u'pk': 5580539929, u'is_verified': False, u'is_private': True}
```

I want to get all the keys
I try

```
for a,b in followers[0]:
  print (followers[0].keys())
```

But it did not work.
What should I do?

and

```
print (followers[0].get(username))
None
```

Answer (score 2):

Guessing from your question, I take it that `followers` is a `list` with `dict` elements.

This means that `followers[0]` will be a single dict containing the information for one of your followers. If you want to display that username, just fetch it without a loop using `followers[0]['username']`.

If you want to display all your followers, loop over the `list` instead:

```
for follower in followers:
  print(follower['username'])
```

Extra hint: know that you can easily get a `list` of your follower's usernames using Python's beautiful list comprehension: `[follower['username'] for follower in followers]`.

Hope this help!